# Windows 10 Lite 22H2. Пропало поле поиска в интерфейсе Проводника, не отображается поле поиска

Tags: windows, интерфейс, цвета, проводник

Windows 10 Lite 22H2. Не видно поля поиска в Проводнике, да и вообще во всех стандартных виндовских окнах, вроде окна Панели управления. То есть, поле существует, но отображается только при наведении на него курсора мышки. Может, кто знает, так и должно быть? Очень уж непривычно, хотелось бы, чтобы это поле отображалось всегда, как на всех прежних версиях. А как его настроить, не пойму. Подскажите, пожалуйста.[image: Рисунок 1 - Окно Windows 10 Lite 22H2 в стандартных цветах с дефектом отображения полей ввода текста]

Comment: тему поставьте дефолтную